# How do you say "to do" When asking a kid what he wants to do when he grows up?

Tags: grammar

The classic question (at least when speaking english) is to ask a child what he wants "to do" when he grows up. Now this "to do" is very vague - and, in a lot of instances, doesn't actually mean "do" (So much as "Be")
I'm interested, in Chinese, how is this classic question asked?

Is it
"你长到以后想干什么啊？“  or is there  a more natural way to say this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's several way to say it. In addition to what you wrote, you can also use `做` or `當`. For example, `長大後你想做什麼?` or `你長大後想當什麼?`

A more formal way, e.g. in essay questions, is to use `志向`. For example: `你未來的志向是什麼?`